# Safely terminating a request outside of handlefunc

Tags: go

How can I safely terminate a request outside of a dispatcher (handlefunc) without an explicit return in handlefunc? In the code below, I end up seeing both "Bad request" and "Not found" in my response, but I'd like f() to abort the request -- so I wouldn't have to clutter dispatcher with error checks and returns.

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func f(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, k string) string{
    if v, ok := r.Form[k]; !ok{     
        http.Error(w, "Bad request", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return ""
    }else{
        return v[0]
    }
}

func main(){
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
        foo := f(w, r, "foo") //make sure foo is passed, if not abort with "bad request" without requiring an explicit return here
        bar := f(w, r, "bar") //make sure bar is passed, if not abort with "bad request" without requiring an explicit return here
        //lookup in db...
        //abort with a 404 if not found in db
        http.NotFound(w, r)         
    })  

    http.ListenAndServe(":6000", nil)
}
```

The above was an attempt to refactor the following:

```
func main(){
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
        if foo,ok:=r.Form["foo"];!ok{
            http.Error(w, "Bad request", http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }
        if bar,ok:=r.Form["bar"];!ok{
            http.Error(w, "Bad request", http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }
        //lookup in db...
        //abort with a 404 if not found in db
        http.NotFound(w, r)         
    })  

    http.ListenAndServe(":6000", nil)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "terminating a request"? And why do you not want to use an explicit `return` in your handler?

Comment: @Ainar-G Edited to show the code repetition I'm trying to avoid. Terminating in the normal sense. Returns would result in lots of clutter especially if I'm checking for more than 1 query string parameter.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without an explicit `return`. The best you can do is `if bar = checkForm(r, w, "bar"); bar == "" { return }`. I'd leave the code as it is though, because it's more explicit.

Comment: what's so bad about a `return`? Go relies on explicit error handling. Trying to write this like python or ruby is only going to make your life hard.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think trying to abort from within a function is what you want to do here. Instead, make the validation less repetitive. You could write something like `package validate` with `func Require(form url.Values, required ...string) error`, and, in your handler, `if err := validate.Require(r.Form, "foo", "bar"); err != nil { ... }`.

Or you could do a more general validator: maybe take a `map` of field name to validation type (number, string, etc.) and return another `map` that's `nil` if no errors and `{"fieldName": error}` otherwise.

[Redditors talked some about this](http://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/1r6hsv/how_do_you_all_go_about_validating_user_input/) and one wrote [a library that uses struct tags to validate](https://github.com/mccoyst/validate). There's another struct-based validation implementation in a [new form rendering/validation toolkit](https://github.com/cjtoolkit/form). (I've tried neither.) The Redditors raised the tricky question of how much you can abstract validation before getting a "framework" that gets in the way when your app gets more complicated, and I don't have a simple answer.

---

There are cases where something really unexpected happens and the server can't do anything better than give the user an opaque "500 Internal Server Error" response, but the problem manifests deep below your `HandlerFunc`. The canonical example is a programming error like a nil pointer dereference. [The advice from the Go team](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#errors) is to use `panic` when "the error is unrecoverable." (A tool like [`negroni.Recovery`](https://github.com/codegangsta/negroni) can help log `panic`s, etc.)

Unnecessary `panic`s are lame because:

- `panic`s make it easier to forget necessary error handling entirely, because it's *implied* that things can `panic` but *explicit* they can `err`
- `panic`/`recover` error handling code is ugly and hard to maintain
- `panic`s introduce inconsistency with the standard `err` returns
- `panic`s use stack unwinding, which is much slower than normal control flow

I did a quick `grep` and essentially all calls to `panic` in the standard library and other official repositories are there to catch programming/internal errors, not crash on surprise external conditions like bad input or I/O errors. Things like file/object not found or invalid user input can usually be handled more gracefully than by crashing the request (it's at least possible to return a specific error), and they aren't really unexpected (it's the Internet; you'll get invalid input and requests for things that don't exist). So `panic` is **not** for normal request aborts--it's for crashing when what "can't happen" has happened and the request can't continue.

---

Again, here, I'd handle invalid input with a standard `if` block in the handler function, but rearrange your validation so that it doesn't require a lot of code per required argument.

Comment: I wouldn't even propose `panic` here. `panic` is generally for indicating a programmer error or when you want to the program to crash with a stack trace. It will also only net you an InternalServerError unless you write your own recovery. There's better ways to do it with normal error handling.

Comment: I'm not proposing `panic` for validation; I edited to try and make that clearer just now. But there's a general question here that's independent of the sample use case ("how do you abort outside the `HandlerFunc`?"), so rather than just suggesting you can't, I'm saying you shouldn't for validation and giving the reasons and an alternative.

Comment: (Expanded and strengthened "don't panic" and added a little meat to "how to validate" as well.)